# Redirect specific urls with .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, redirect

I previously had a blog in two languages. I installed a multilanguage plugin for that purpose. I regretted doing this and now I bought another domain for one specific language, and want to redirect all the posts and pages of this language to the new domain.

In other words, if someone types `mydomain.com/pl/` or `mydomain.com/pl/post/` redirect him to `mydomain.pl` or `mydomain.pl/post/`

Is it possible to apply an universal rule that if I redirect `mydomain.com/pl/` to `mydomain.pl` every other related urls will be redirected as well, instead of doing it one by one? How to do that?

I've tried this that I've seen in another forum but with no luck. Truth is I'm a bit confused with this.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com\pl$   [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://mydomain.pl/  [L,R]
```

I hope I have explained myself well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mydomain\.com$
RewriteRule ^pl/(.*)$ http://mydomain.pl/$1 [R=301,L]
```

The host name is always lower case so you don't need [NC] and maybe in your case you want to have permanent redirects so you can use R=301.

Comment: Never test with 301 Redirects. These are **permanent**. Always test using `R` or `R=302` as this is a temporary redirect.

Comment: Your rule doesnt work on htaccess context as it contains a leading slash in the pattern. Remove it or make it optional using a **?**

Comment: It worked! Thanks for the advice thickguru I did like you said, and @starkeen was right, it didn't work the first time, but then I removed the leading slash as he said and worked perfectly. Thanks to the 3 of you!